# What is *this and what is this

Tags: c++, c++17

I have an simple beginner questions. Here is the code block:

```
  SimpleString& operator=(const SimpleString& other) {
    if(this == &other)
      return *this;
    const auto new_buffer = new char[other.max_size];
    delete[] buffer;
    buffer = new_buffer;
    length = other.length;
    max_size = other.max_size;
    std::strncpy(buffer, other.buffer, max_size);
    return *this;
  }
```

Here ist the full code: https://pastebin.com/2qYxq10q

I dont understand, why `this` is a pointer in the second line and
`*this` in the third line should also be pointer, because the return type of the method has to be a pointer.
In my perception in the third line should also stand `this` and not `*this`.

Has anybody at least a link with the explanation.

Comment: The return type is a reference, not a pointer.

Comment: @tkausl see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in   A reference is a pointer but is a constant pointer.

Comment: @barlop thats an implementation detail.

Comment: @tkausl well it's an implementation detail that conflicts with, (shows to be wrong?)  the idea that a reference is not a pointer. From what I can tell, a pointer is an address, as is a reference. The issue is whether one is talking of an address stored in a memory location, or an address of a memory location (where you're not fetching the address from a memory location).

Comment: @barlop That's a very mixed up explanation. References are not pointers, you're thinking about how they might be implemented, but from the language point of view they are different entities.

Comment: @john I see what u mean.. e.g. "pass by reference" is passing a reference.. in the C++ sense of the term..   I think java might use the term reference differently. In java a value that is a pointer to an object, might be called a reference or object ref and in java u can't do &var or even *var. So in C++ terminology a ref is an address that merely marks a location and is not a value in a location. Given that pass by ref goes by C++ terminology,  I wonder if maybe the C++ terminological distinction between reference and pointer,is  the standard/conventional/traditional  one in Comp Sci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of the method is a reference not a pointer. In `SimpleString&` the `&` means reference, a pointer would be `SimpleString*`.

Comment: I have understand, that there is a difference between pointers and references. But that is not my core question. 

The method expects to return a reference but returns a pointer?

Comment: If `p` is a pointer to something, then the expression `*p` is a reference to the same thing.